# program that adds 1, 2, or 3, until it reaches 21

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, do-while

I am making a program called "count 21". How it's supposed to work is, "Two people play the game of Count 21 by taking turns entering a 1, 2, or 3, which is
added to a running total. The player who adds the value that makes the total exceed
21 loses the game. Create a game of Count 21 in which a player competes against the
computer, and program a strategy that always allows the computer to win. On any
turn, if the player enters a value other than 1, 2, or 3, force the player to reenter the
value."
I am having trouble figuring out how I should do this, this is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Count21 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x; //running total
    int y; //input num
    String strInput = "";
    String message = "";
    String answer = "";

    do {
        strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome to Count 21. \n In this game you will play against "
            + "the computer and add the numbers 1, 2, or 3 together. \n Whoever pushes the "
            + "numbers over 21 loses. \n Do you want to add 1, 2, or 3? "
            + "(please enter the number you choose.");
        y = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
        x++; 
        if (y == 1) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose the number 1."
            + " 1 will be added to the running total of" + (x + 1) +" .");
        }
        else if (y == 2) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You chose the number 2."
           + "2 will be added to the running total of" + (x + 2) + " .");
        }
        else if (y == 3) {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "You chose the number 3."
            + "3 will be added to the running total of" + (x + 3) + " .");
        }
        else{ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You didn't type a valid number, please try again. \n");
       }
    } while (x > 21);
}
}
```

After the program runs and the user types in the number they chose the program ends. This is all I have so far, but I am stuck on how to keep the number's from the user adding until it reaches 21. I also am unsure of how to make the computer win the game. I think I should be using a for loop?
Any advice or comments are greatly appreciated. I apologize if my code or question is unclear.

Comment: If I were you I would pick Swing or console. It's clumsy to use both. Edit: Also, you increment `x` on every iteration. If you want `x` to reflect the sum of all the user's inputs, then remove `x++` and add `x += y` to some part of the loop.

Comment: You have a few issues but I would start by changing your while condition to x < 21

Comment: Along with what Darth is saying, you can just use `x` in your Strings if you do `x += y` instead of `x++`

Comment: Is this a Java question or an algorithm question? Please clarify whether you know how to program the computer player and if you do please describe the algorithm in plain words outside of the code.

Comment: It would be a question over both programming the computer player so it wins and also over the algorithm

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you shouldn't be incrementing `x`by one for each time a value is entered. This also causes further problems as when invalid numbers are entered it would still get incremented. Instead you should be checking the value of `y` and then adding the appropriate amount within the conditional logic (IF statement). This should also simplify the output messages contained within the logic, as you shouldn't need to add anything to x when printing it.

Again, as stated in the comments, the while condition should be `x < 21`.